# Is this my drawing of domain of $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}\mid-{1\over 2}\leq y\leq x\leq{1\over 2}\}$ correct?

Tags: inequality, integral-domain

I want you to check my depiction of the region shown below of multiple integral is correct or not. I think that it seems correct but cannot have a strong confidence.

$$
A:=\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}~\Bigg|~-{1\over 2}\leq y\leq x\leq{1\over 2}\right\}
$$

[image]

$$\begin{align}
-{1\over 2}\leq y\leq x\leq{1\over 2}&\equiv\left(-{1\over 2}\le y\le x\right)\land\left(-{1\over 2}\le x\le{1\over 2}\right)\\&\land\left(-{1\over 2}\le y\le{1\over 2}\right)\land\left(y\le x\le{1\over 2}\right)
\end{align}$$

Comment: I know that I should had written the drawing using tikz but it is too time taking..

Comment: Isn't it $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}\mid{\color{red}-1\over 2}\leq y\leq x\leq{1\over 2}\}$?

Comment: Ahh,  I will fix it.

Comment: ${-1\over 2}\leq y\leq x\leq{1\over 2}\iff\left(-{1\over 2}\le y\le \frac12\right)\land\left(y\le x\right)\land\left(-\frac12\le x\le{1\over 2}\right)$

Comment: Yes, your picture is correct, due to$${-1\over 2}\leq y\leq x\leq{1\over 2}\iff\left(-{1\over 2}\le y\land y\le x\land x\le{1\over 2}\right)$$(intersection of 3 halfplanes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The domain is given by $3$ conditions

$\cdot\ \ $  $y \ge - \frac{1}{2}$

$\cdot\ \ $  $ y \le x$

$\cdot\ \ $  $x \le \frac{1}{2}$

so a triangle. Yes, the picture is OK.